# URL mapping not working properly from controller.xql

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I've been trying to forward the file to HTML template but it's not working. Here is the code in file.xql

```
{
for $resource in collection('/db/apps/myapp/data')
let $doc := request:get-parameter("filename", ())
let $uri := document-uri( root( $resource ) )

return
    <a href="{$uri}"> {document-uri( root( $resource ) )}</a>
};
```

and here is controller.xql

```
    if ($exist:path eq '') then
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <redirect url="{request:get-uri()}/"/>
    </dispatch>
    
else if ($exist:path eq "/") then
    (: forward root path to index.xql :)
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <redirect url="index.html"/>
    </dispatch>

else if (ends-with($exist:resource, ".html")) then
    (: the html page is run through view.xql to expand templates :)
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <view>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
        </view>
        <error-handler>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/error-page.html" method="get"/>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
        </error-handler>
    </dispatch>
else if (contains($exist:path, "/data/")) then

    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">

           <forward url="{$exist:controller}/templates/file.html"/>
        <view>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql">
                <add-parameter name="filename" value="{$exist:resource}.xml"/>
            </forward>
        </view>
    </dispatch>
```

But it goes to URL "http://localhost:8080/db/apps/myapp/data/let001.xml"
and not to "http://localhost:8080/db/apps/myapp/templates/file.html"
Any ideas what is wrong in the code?

Comment: Hi Regina, there's not enough information in your post to understand the situation. I'd suggest posting the application source code somewhere (like GitHub), and updating the post to point to the files. Then we will also need to know the step-by-step behavior you expect vs. the behavior you are experiencing. Also, what version of eXist are you using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.